# Retrieving ID's order by date with pagination where between two dates

Tags: redis

I have sorted set like this:

```
Student Registrations
ID   SCORE
1    1437809702647
2    1437770121955
3    1437766535972
```

I want to retrieve student ids between two dates and ordered in 2nd page and 3rd page (every page has 10  records)

what would be your proposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution:

```
zrangebyscore student:registrations 1431550800000 1432069200000 LIMIT 0 10 WITHSCORES
```

Detailed:

```
zrangebyscore / zrevrangebyscore 
KEY 
WHERE_CONDITION(min max) 
PAGINATION(LIMIT page*rowCountPerPage rowCountPerPage)
```

for sorting [zrangebyscore](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) or [zrevrangebyscore](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrangebyscore)